# How to write single-line comments in an H2O template

Tags: php, templates, templating-engine

How can I write single-line comments in an [H2O template](http://www.h2o-template.org/)?

Django's template engine allows the syntax `{# a single-line comment #}` for single-line comments, but this does not seem to be available in H2O. There is no trace of it [in the documentation](https://github.com/speedmax/h2o-php/wiki/Built-in-tags), and testing reveals it does not work.

Is there a way to write single-line comments in an H2O template? Or is there a way I could implement a similar tag with the briefest syntax possible?

Answer (score 1):

The single line comment:

```
{* single line comment *}
```

**As found on the documentation under:**

*A good usage of branching display content, use white space, comment*